# bug with my zsh in the terminal (linux)?

Tags: linux

i have some trouble with my terminal in linux.
When i start my terminal i have this line:

This is the Z Shell configuration function for new users,
zsh-newuser-install.
You are seeing this message because you have no zsh startup files
(the files .zshenv, .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin in the directory
~).  This function can help you with a few settings that should
make your use of the shell easier.

You can:

(q)  Quit and do nothing.  The function will be run again next time.

(0)  Exit, creating the file ~/.zshrc containing just a comment.
     That will prevent this function being run again.

(1)  Continue to the main menu.

(2)  Populate your ~/.zshrc with the configuration recommended
     by the system administrator and exit (you will need to edit
     the file by hand, if so desired).

--- Type one of the keys in parentheses ---

how i run zsh ? 
And when i press "2" i have this :

cp: not writing through dangling symlink '/home/thomas/.zshrc'
zsh-newuser-install:source:982: no such file or directory: /home/thomas/.zshrc

thx for the help.

Answer (score -3):

zsh is an uncommon choice on linux. If your account is on somebody else's system, ask the sysadmin to fix it up for you. If you installed it, look at .zshrc with ls -l : the 'dangling symlink' suggests it exists but points to somewhere else (that suggests an admin or distro install) and the place it is pointing to does not exist.

If you can identify where it should be pointing (I'm assuming now that this *is* a distro install), fix the symlink. Otherwise ask on a distro list or forum.